# Ember-CLI with Mirage gives me this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroyRecord' of undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

I'm trying to create a simple Ember-CLI app with mirage mock server. I can insert and generate random data in the database but I can't delete a record.

My application.hbs

```
<h2 id="title">Contacts</h2>

{{#each contact in model}}
<table>
<tr>    
  <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
  <td>{{contact.surname}}</td>
  <td>{{contact.age}}</td>
  <td><button {{action 'deleteContact'}}>X</button></td>  //button to delete the contact
</tr>
</table>
{{/each}}

<br>
<p>New contact</p>
{{input value=newName}}
<button {{action 'createContact' newName}}>Create contact</button>
```

And in application.js I define the actions

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() 
    {
        return this.store.findAll('contact');
    },

    actions: 
    {
        createContact(newName)
        {
            this.store.createRecord('contact',
            {
                name: newName
            }).save();
        },

        deleteContact(contact) 
        {   
            return contact.destroyRecord(); // if I comment this line the error doesn't show
        }
    }
});
```

When I click the button I get this error in Ember inspector: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroyRecord' of undefineddeleteContact @ application.js:18triggerEvent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `contact` record instance to your action `deleteContact` with signature `deleteContact (contact)`.

```
<button {{action 'deleteContact' contact}}>X</button></td>
```